# Your app is sending Advertising ID over an unencrypted connection with AdMob + StartApp Ads

Tags: android, admob, startapp

I am showing **`Admob + StartApp Ads`**. I have implemented **`Admob Mediation`** to show ads in my android app. I have uploaded my app to **Pre Launch** in `google play`, it show warning in report.

> Your app is sending Advertising ID over an unencrypted connection.

Anyone know how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Any chance you are using `http` instead of `https`?

Comment: No, every ads shown is https @Tigger

Comment: Are you using `http` at all, **anywhere in the App** where the ads are used instead of `https` is what I meant.

Comment: Yes, but its not related with Loading Ads.

Comment: The Advertising ID is used by third party libraries, i.e. Adobe, Krux, etc and they sometimes do not follow best practices. You should look into any of those libs, and see if there are settings for enforcing https or you can update the libraries that use https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted **StartApp Ad Provider Team** , and they have **updated** their library and now it works fine without this error with new library.